# CSS- removing hr tag space not working

Tags: html, css

I have read multiple posts, I've followed the instructions and still no change. What I am after is to remove the space in between the hr tag and my form. I thought by setting the `margin` and `padding` to `0` would do the fix, instead I'm getting this:

[image]

But instead I want something like the image below - just with a line in separating the fields.

[image]

**html**

```html
<label for="Fridss" class="label"> F </label>
<button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-default addButton" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
<input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Fri" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="16">
<span>-</span>
<input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Friday" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="17">
<hr />
```

**css**

```css
hr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #58585b;
}
.open_hours {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

or is there a better way of creating lines in css.

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle where we can debug the actual issue

Comment: i have checked your code 
https://jsfiddle.net/95tcdeuu/
everything is ok, maybe you have some css other than this, that affect hr margin or padding, you can use browser inspect element to find where it is

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @MoshFeu i am using safari

Comment: @SaeedTaran found it was the bootstrap.css which was causing the problem, but the answers below helped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really does depend on the browser's built-in styles. Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abstractecho/7a3gzpqL/

```
body{color: black;}
hr {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #58585b;
}
.open_hours {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

You may want to check if adding an margin: 0 !important to your hr css to override browser styles and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, the bootstrap css i included was causing the problem, but the !important tags seemed to resolve it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays `hr` tag is used very seldom, and if you need semantic markup, you may to use css-property `border`. In your case, you have classic list including similar elements, so semantic way to use `ul` tag and include every line in `li` tags.

```
<li>
  <label for="Fridss" class="label"> M </label>
  <button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="fa fa-plus-square-o addButton" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  </button>
  <input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Fri" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="16"> -
  <input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Friday" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="17">
</li>
```

```
li {
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #58585b;
}
```

I used your code, removed all extra tags (to my mind) and created [JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/y6jvnk3g/) with your code

Answer (score 2):

try  adding a div for each input: https://jsfiddle.net/7nww2tmw/

```
<div class="box">
  <label for="Fridss" class="label"> F </label>
  <button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-default addButton" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  <input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Fri" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="16">
  <span>-</span>
  <input type="text" name="Fridss" id="Friday" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="17">
</div>
```

css:

```
.open_hours {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 29px;
  border: dotted 1px #f00;
  float: left;
  border-left: #ff0000;
  border-right: #ff0000;
  border-top: #ff0000;
}
```